# How to get clean GET urls for search in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, clean-url

Currently I'm working on a project search functionality in Laravel and stuck in to get clean GET urls <strike>without any kind of JS</strike> JS will work too

like when I search my form redirects me to

http://jobs.localhost/search?q=hello

but instead, I want this

[http://jobs.localhost/search/hello](http://jobs.localhost/search?q=hello)

My web.php is:

```
Route::get('search', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
```

Form is:

```
<form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{{ action('SearchController@search') }}" id="search-form">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 nopadding">
        <div class="form-group">

            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-q" name="q" placeholder="Search a Job">
            <i class="icon-magnifying-glass"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 nopadding">
        <div class="form-group form-action">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-search-submit">Search <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Currently In controller I'm just printing the value:

```
 public function search(Request $request)
 {
  echo $request['q'];  
 }
```

I've already checked multiple solutions of JS or POST but none works for me this is the final output I'm looking for:  [http://jobs.localhost/search/hello](http://jobs.localhost/search?q=hello)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change route to:

```
Route::get('search/{search}', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);
```

And controller to:

```
public function search(Request $request, $search)
{
    echo $search;  
}
```

Then you'll be able to do something like this with jQuery:

```
$('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var search = $('#form-q').val();
    window.location('/search/' + search);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is route parameters. You can find more info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-parameters).

A problem you can (and will) run into is that the route for the form is determined in php (server side), but the search parameter is determined as input. If you don't want any javascript I believe this is impossible without rerouting.

Comment: I included Route parameter but It gives me an error  `Missing required parameters for [Route: search] [URI: search/{q}]`

Comment: This is my web route `Route::get('search/{q}', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SearchController@search']);`

Comment: When you use a route parameter you also need to include it when you make the request. For example "action('SearchController@search', ['q' => 'test'])"

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. It gives me this url `http://jobs.localhost/search/test?q=s` which I don't want actually.

Comment: yes, that is the problem i mentioned in my answer, you will need some javascript/rerouting to solve this. I merely showed the path to a solution

Comment: Can you add the JS solution so I can get working it. I edited my question.

Comment: Alexey has a nice answer for that